# Disable *-subscription-store-changelog topic creation for foreign key join in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When we do foreign key join in kafka streams, it creates 3 state stores (as given on [confluent page](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-enrichment-with-kafka-streams-foreign-key-joins/)) :

> The three state stores involved are:
>
> 1. left-STATE-STORE-0000000000: The left-hand-side KTable store.
> 2. right-STATE-STORE-0000000003: The left-hand-side KTable store.
> 3. myjoin-subscription-store: The subscription store for the join. This is the new data structure discussed above. Regardless of the operation name, this store is always suffixed -subscription-store. *Note for your capacity planning that this store will also have a corresponding changelog, called **myjoin-subscription-store-changelog***.

Can we disable this **myjoin-subscription-store-changelog** topic creation?

I know for source topics KTable materialization, we can disable this by adding Materialized.withLggingDisabled().

But, Materialized.withLggingDisabled() does not seem to work while doing join. I tried passing this argument while doing join as below, but it did not work:

```
KTable<K, V> ktable = leftKTable.join(rightKTable, 
    foreignKeyExtractor, 
    joiner, 
    Named.as("dummy-topic"), 
    Materialized.<K, V, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
        with(KeySerde, ValueSerde)
        .withLoggingDisabled());
```

I was still getting the error:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create topic [application.id]-dummy-topic-subscription-store-changelog.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:150)
    ....
```

Comment: It's currently not possible to disable this changelog. The `Materialize` config you pass in, is for the join result table only. Can you file a ticket for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/

Comment: Raised a ticket for this - [KAFKA-15337](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15337).